# Brussels Sprout game in python

Tags: python, class, location, boolean, symbols

Here's the code in python for a game where one or two rat eats brussels sprouts. It contains a Rat class and Maze class:

```
class Rat:
""" A rat caught in a maze. """
    # Write your Rat methods here.
    def __init__(Rat, symbol, row, col):
        Rat.symbol = symbol
        Rat.row = row
        Rat.col = col

        num_sprouts_eaten = 0

    def set_location(Rat, row, col):

        Rat.row = row
        Rat.col = col

    def eat_sprout(Rat):
        num_sprouts_eaten += 1        

    def __str__(Rat):
        """ (Contact) -> str

        Return a string representation of this contact.
        """
        result = ''

        result = result + '{0} '.format(Rat.symbol) + 'at '

        result = result + '('+ '{0}'.format(Rat.row) + ', '
        result = result + '{0}'.format(Rat.col) + ') ate '
        result = result + str(num_sprouts_eaten) + ' sprouts.'
        return result


class Maze:
    """ A 2D maze. """

    # Write your Maze methods here.
    def __init__(Maze, content, rat_1, rat_2):
        Maze.content= [content]

        Maze.rat_1 = RAT_1_CHAR
        Maze.rat_2 = RAT_2_CHAR

    def is_wall(Maze, row,col):
        walls = False

        if WALL in Maze.content[row*col]:
            walls = True
        return walls
```

now if i initialize the class by calling the maze and locations of Rats 1 and Rats 2.

```
Maze([['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], 
      ['#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#'], 
      ['#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#'], 
      ['#', '.', '.', '@', '#', '.', '#'], 
      ['#', '@', '#', '.', '@', '.', '#'], 
      ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']], 
      Rat('J', 1, 1),
      Rat('P', 1, 4))
```

The character '#' represents a wall, '.' represents the hallway or path and '@' represents a brussels sprout each...

now how can I make sure that the boolean is True if a wall ('#') is in a particular set location that the rat runs into and it returns False if there is no wall in that particular set location? in this case either a hallway or a brussels sprout?

P.S.. here is the definition of RAT_1_CHAR = 'J' RAT_2_CHAR = 'P' down below right before the Rats and Maze classes...thnx

```
# Do not import any modules. If you do, the tester may reject your submission.
# Constants for the contents of the maze.
# The visual representation of a wall.
WALL = '#'
# The visual representation of a hallway.
HALL = '.'
# The visual representation of a brussels sprout.
SPROUT = '@'
# Constants for the directions. Use these to make Rats move.
# The left direction.
LEFT = -1
# The right direction.
RIGHT = 1
# No change in direction.
NO_CHANGE = 0
# The up direction.
UP = -1
# The down direction.
DOWN = 1
# The letters for rat_1 and rat_2 in the maze.
RAT_1_CHAR = 'J'
RAT_2_CHAR = 'P'
num_sprouts_eaten = 0
```

Comment: Where are `RAT_1_CHAR` and `RAT_2_CHAR` defined? Why are you using them instead of `rat_1` and `rat_2`, which the function accepts as parameters?

Comment: By convention, the first argument in a class method definition should be `self`. Do you have a good reason to use `Rat` or `Maze` instead?

Comment: i felt Rat and Maze were easier to deine...i changed stuff and the RAT_1_CHAR and RAT_2_CHAR represent the letters J and P respectively

Comment: In what way is using `Maze` as the argument name easier than using `self`? If anything, `Maze` is _harder_ to type because it has a capital letter.

Comment: well i'm confused now...cause i've done over 50% of it this way using Rat and Maze for the latter to input any maze!!!

Comment: Look, Ben, I'm sure you're a nice guy and I don't mean to put you down, but you obviously have no idea what you're doing. Maybe you should learn Python before trying to program this?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `Maze.content = [content]` instead of just `= content`? You're taking a 2D maze (a list of lists) and storing it inside a 3D maze with a "height" of 1 (a list of one list of lists). This means every access to it is going to be more complicated—instead of `content[r][c]`, you'll have to do `content[0][r][c]`. Did you do this intentionally?

Comment: That should probably be `self.content = content`, not `Maze.content = whatever`.

Answer (score 3):

```
def is_wall(self, row, col): return self.content[row][col] == '#'
```

Your syntax for accessing list items is wrong. So is your syntax for defining member functions. There's no way any of this would run.

When you're learning a language, always make sure to try writing and executing small programs (in this case, a program containing a single class) before building larger ones.

Comment: it is a boolean...how can i get this fixed if it is a boolean? is_wall method is a boolean!

Comment: Yes, this function returns a Boolean (True/False).

Comment: The function defined by Anubhav does return a boolean value.

self.content[row][col] returns the 'col-th' item in the 'row-th' item of self.content - so, for instance, self.content[2][0] will return the 0th item (remember, computers start counting from zero) of the 2nd item of self.content (more simply, the 0th item of the 2nd row).

a == b returns True if a is equal to b, and returns False otherwise.

Thus, self.content[row][col] == "#" returns True if the 'col-th' item of the 'row-th' item of self.content is equal to "#", and False otherwise.

Comment: i got this error message when i tried it  - >>> is_wall(1,1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#107>", line 1, in <module>
    is_wall(1,1)
NameError: name 'is_wall' is not defined

Comment: @BenStein: If `is_wall` is a method of `Maze`, you can't just write `is_wall(1, 1)`; you have to have a `Maze` instance to call it on. (If you think about it, the question you're trying to ask doesn't even make sense in English. "Is location (1, 1) in a maze a wall?" The answer is "It depends on the contents of the particular maze in question. Which maze?")  For example, if you've done `my_maze = Maze(my_content, my_rat1, my_rat2)`, then you can write `my_maze.is_wall(1, 1)`.

Comment: i did and i get this  message - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#116>", line 1, in <module>
    d.is_wall(1,3)
  File "C:\Users\gijoe\Downloads\a2.py", line 83, in is_wall
    return (Maze.content[row][col] == '#')
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: As [abarnert says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322163/brussels-sprout-game-in-python/16322438?noredirect=1#comment23374390_16322163), that's because you've set `Maze.content = [content]`.  Change that to `self.content = content`.

Comment: i gotta have nested lists on it - a list o a list